# How to prepend a column to a matrix?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Ok, imagine I have this Matrix: {{1,2},{2,3}}, and I'd rather have {{4,1,2},{5,2,3}}. That is, I prepended a column to the matrix. Is there an easy way to do it?

My best proposal is this:

```
PrependColumn[vector_List, matrix_List] := 
 Outer[Prepend[#1, #2] &, matrix, vector, 1]
```

But it obfuscates the code and constantly requires loading more and more code. Isn't this built in somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `ArrayFlatten` was introduced in Mathematica 6 the least obfuscated solution must be

```
matrix = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}
vector = {{4}, {5}}

ArrayFlatten@{{vector, matrix}}
```

A nice trick is that replacing any matrix block with `0` gives you a zero block of the right size.

Answer (score 7):

I think the least obscure is the following way of doing this is:

```
PrependColumn[vector_List, matrix_List] := MapThread[Prepend, {matrix, vector}];
```

In general, `MapThread` is the function that you'll use most often for tasks like this one (I use it all the time when adding labels to arrays before formating them nicely with `Grid`), and it can make things a lot clearer and more concise to use `Prepend` instead of the equivalent `Prepend[#1, #2]&`.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the most common way is to transpose, prepend, and transpose again:

```
PrependColumn[vector_List, matrix_List] := 
  Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[matrix], vector]]
```

Answer (score 0):

THE... ABSOLUTELY.. BY FAR... FASTEST method to append or prepend a column from my tests of various methods on array `RandomReal[100,{10^8,5}]` (kids, don't try this at home... if your machine isn't built for speed and memory, operations on an array this size are guaranteed to hang your computer)
...is this: `Append[tmp\[Transpose], Range@Length@tmp]\[Transpose]`.
Replace `Append` with `Prepend` at will.

The next fastest thing is this: `Table[tmp[[n]]~Join~{n}, {n, Length@tmp}]` - almost twice as slow.

Comment: Apparently you missed the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270802/inserting-into-a-2d-list/4270825#4270825. Using `ArrayFlatten` seems to be faster.