# Appending to the rows of a table

Tags: arrays, append, wolfram-mathematica

I have a two dimensional list and a one dimensional list. I would like to insert the 1D list into the 2D list as an additional column. For example:

```
array = {{a,1,2},{b,2,3},{c,3,4}};
column = {x,y,z};
```

becomes

```
final = {{a,1,2,x},{b,2,3,y},{c,3,4,z}};
```

I have done this inelegantly:

```
Table[Insert[array[[i]], column[[i]], 4], {i, Length[array]}];
```

My question: what is the proper way to do this in Mathematica? I don't think it needs the loop I'm using. My solution feels ugly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example:

```
 Transpose@Append[Transpose@array, column]
```

You can also make is a function like so:

```
 subListAppend = Transpose@Append[Transpose@#1, #2] &;
 subListAppend[array, column]
```

which makes it easier if you have to use it frequently. And of course if you want to insert at any place other than just the end you can use `Insert[]`.

```
subListInsert = Transpose@Insert[Transpose@#1, #2, #3] &;
subListInsert[array, column, 2]
--> {{a, x, 1, 2}, {b, y, 2, 3}, {c, z, 3, 4}}
```

EDIT: Since the obligatory speed optimization discussion has started, here are some results using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/4199042#4199042) and a 10000x200 array:

```
ArrayFlatten@{{array, List /@ column}}:             0.020 s
Transpose@Append[Transpose@array, column]:          0.067 s
MapThread[Append, {array, column}]:                 0.083 s  
MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, 4] &, {array, column}]:    0.095 s
Map[Flatten, Flatten[{array, column}, {2}]]:        0.26 s
ConstantArray based solution:                       0.29 s
Partition[Flatten@Transpose[{array, column}], 4]:   0.48 s
```

And the winner is `ArrayFlatten`!

Comment: Alright, that did the trick, thank you! Now I need to pick that apart to understand *why*, but that's for me to do.

Comment: Go one element at a time (e.g. see what Transpose@array does) and you'll figure it out :-).

Comment: Yep, that helped. It's like origami. I knew I was fighting Mathematica unnecessarily. Thanks again.

Comment: Using `ArrayFlatten` often looks nicer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244782/how-to-prepend-a-column-to-a-matrix/2274679#2274679

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is

```
result = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[array] + {0, 1}];
result[[All, 1 ;; Last[Dimensions[array]]]] = array;
result[[All, -1]] = column;
```

which seems to be faster on my computer for large numeric matrices, although it requires an additional variable.  If you're dealing with real-valued entries you'll want to use

```
result = ConstantArray[0.0, Dimensions[array] + {0, 1}];
```

to keep the speed gains.

There's also

```
MapThread[Append, {array, column}]
```

which is also fast (and elegant IMO) but will unpack the result.  (But if you have symbolic entries as in the example, that's not a concern.)

Comment: Thanks Brett. Your MapThread usage is indeed elegant. I'm glad I saw the Transpose answer first because I have a feeling that the concepts it uses are more widely applicable, however this is very, very concise. My matrices are not big enough to warrant the extra lines of code for the ConstantArray approach and they contain mainly symbolic data anyway. Still, four utterly different approaches to the same problem: that's Mathematica!

Comment: Interesting, I get roughly 35% better `Timing` using the OP's example and about a factor of ten better speed for large (1k -- 1M entries) matrices using my method. Most different list manipulations at the kernel level are performed by the same (very optimized) code, so trying to force MMA to do things a certain way (which may be correct / optimal in other languages) most times leads to overhead.

Comment: I was doing my tests with V8 on OS X.

Comment: You mean the javascript engine? I'm confused. EDIT: oh you mean version 8? Well, I'm using v7.0.1 on OS X.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my try using Join

```
In[11]:= Join[array,List/@column,2]
Out[11]= {{a,1,2,x},{b,2,3,y},{c,3,4,z}}
```

It might be comparable to the fastest one among previously mentioned programs.

Comment: I am surprised a `Join` method was not already on this page, as it seems like one of the most natural (and efficient) ways to do this. +1

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
pos = 4;
MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, pos] &, {array, column}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I (sometimes) like to transpose with Flatten, as it works with a 'ragged' array.

```
Map[Flatten, Flatten[{array, column}, {2}]]
```

giving

{{a, 1, 2, x}, {b, 2, 3, y}, {c, 3, 4, z}}

But if, say, the column has only 2 elements

```
column2 = {x, y};
Map[Flatten, Flatten[{array, column2}, {2}]]
```

giving

{{a, 1, 2, x}, {b, 2, 3, y}, {c, 3, 4}}

(Transpose will not work here)

Answer (score 2):

Still:

```
k= Partition[Flatten@Transpose[{#, {x, y, z}}], 4]&

k@ {{a, 1, 2}, {b, 2, 3}, {c, 3, 4}}

(*
-> {{a, 1, 2, x}, {b, 2, 3, y}, {c, 3, 4, z}}
*)
```

Comment: Make that five approaches. This one's like a sausage: you can eat it, but you don't want to see how it's made :)

Answer (score 1):

Though not as practical or efficient as some of the extant methods, here are two more to add to the list:

```
ArrayPad[array, {0,{0,1}}, List /@ column]

PadRight[array, Dimensions[array] + {0, 1}, List /@ column]
```