# Adding a Third column of data in Mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a very large table of data something like:

```
lista = {{2,8},{3,4},{5,2}..}
```

I would like to add x to every element so it would be

```
lista ={{x,2,8},{x,3,4},{x,5,2}.....}
```

This seems to me like it should be rather trivial but I have not been able to find a solution.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very nearly a duplicate of [Appending to the rows of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270802/618728) and an exact duplicate of [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121) on the dedicated site where your question should have been asked.  Many more methods, with timings, are provided in those threads but here are two good methods to start with:

```
lista = {{2, 8}, {3, 4}, {5, 2}};

ArrayPad[lista, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 8}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 2}}
> ```

Or:

```
ArrayFlatten @ {{0, lista}}
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 8}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 5, 2}}
> ```

---

Dedicated StackExchange site:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Join` can be useful here:

```
Map[Join[{x}, #] &, {{2, 8}, {3, 4}, {5, 2}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have two methods for doing this; both of them work fine, but I think the latter is better for technical reasons; although I have not tested their performance:

**First Method:**

```
lista = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
(*{{1, 3}, {0, 3}, {5, 5}, {4, 2}, {1, 7}, {3, 6}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {7, 6}, {8, 10}}*)
For[i = 1, i <= Length[lista], i++, PrependTo[lista[[i]], x]]
lista
(*{{x, 1, 3}, {x, 0, 3}, {x, 5, 5}, {x, 4, 2}, {x, 1, 7}, {x, 3, 6}, {x, 2, 2}, {x, 3, 1}, {x, 7, 6}, {x, 8, 10}}*)
```

**Second Method:**

```
lista = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
(*{{0, 5}, {6, 0}, {4, 6}, {3, 2}, {8, 1}, {4, 9}, {0, 5}, {9, 10}, {3,0}, {8, 4}}*)
X = ConstantArray[x, Length[lista]];
lista = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[lista], X]]
(*{{x, 0, 5}, {x, 6, 0}, {x, 4, 6}, {x, 3, 2}, {x, 8, 1}, {x, 4, 9}, {x,0, 5}, {x, 9,10}, {x, 3, 0}, {x, 8, 4}}*)
```