# Saturation in Mathematica Plots

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, contour, density-plot

I am making some density and contour plots in Mathematica. These plots have very high peaks which saturate with color and prevent me from seeing differences in the peaks. Is there a way I can tone down the color scale so my peaks are not just white blobs?

Trying other color schemes has not worked out.

Cheers,
Ben

In the image below all you see is purple and white, but there is variation in the height of the white areas but it can not be seen because the color is saturated. ColorFunctionScale ->False, only turns everything two colors.

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[photo, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> {True}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Electron Bunch Energy (MeV)", "Photon Energy (keV)", 
"", "Yield (Photons/Sr e-KeV)" }, LabelStyle -> {15}, 
InterpolationOrder -> 10]
```

Comment: Your way to go is using an adjusted `ColorFunction` with `ColorFunctionScaling` set to `False` but without a specific example it is hard to give a general answer. Can you create a minimal code snip which shows what you try to avoid?

Comment: I added some explanation in an edit.

Comment: Perhaps some way of displaying the color on a log scale?

Comment: Ben, on average you're going to get more and better answers if you ask your *Mathematica* questions on [the proper site.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok thanks, I was unaware of the site.

Comment: Since you Accepted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18372279/618728) (thanks) in which I pointed it out rather loudly I am surprised.  I guess I have to make my banner bigger. :^)