# Mathematica "AppendTo" function problem

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm a newbie in Mathematica and I'm having a major malfunction with adding columns to a data table. I'm running Mathematica 7 in Vista. I have spent a lot of time RFD before asking here.

I have a data table (mydata) with three columns and five rows. I'm trying to add two lists of five elements to the table (effectively adding two columns to the data table).

This works *perfectly*:

```
Table[AppendTo[mydata[[i]],myfirstlist[[i]]],{i,4}]
```

Printing out the table with: `mydata // TableForm` shows the added column.

However, when I try to add my second list

```
Table[AppendTo[mydata[[i]],mysecondlist[[i]]],{i,5}]
```

either Mathematica crashes(!) or I get a slew of `Part::partw` and `Part::spec` errors saying  Part 5 does not exist.

However, after all the error messages (if Mathematica does not crash), again printing out the data table with: `mydata // TableForm` shows the data table with five columns just like I intended. All `TableForm` formatting options on the revised data table work fine.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to have `{i,5}` rather than `{i,4}` at the end of your first appending operation? (I don't think this has anything to do with your problem.)

Answer (score 6):

Let's try to clarify what the double transpose method consists of. I make no claims about the originality of the approach. My focus is on the clarity of exposition.

Let's begin with 5 lists. First we'll place three in a table. Then we'll add the final two.

```
food = {"bagels", "lox", "cream cheese", "coffee", "blueberries"};
mammals = {"fisher cat", "weasel", "skunk", "raccon", "squirrel"};
painters = {"Picasso", "Rembrandt", "Klee", "Rousseau", "Warhol"};
countries = {"Brazil", "Portugal", "Azores", "Guinea Bissau", 
             "Cape Verde"};
sports = {"golf", "badminton", "football", "tennis", "rugby"};
```

The first three lists--food, mammals, painters--become the elements of `lists3`.  They are just lists, but `TableForm` displays them in a table as **rows**.

```
(lists3 = {food, mammals, painters}) // TableForm
```

[image: lists3]

`mydata` will be the name for `lists3` transposed.   Now the three lists appear as **columns**.  That's what transposition does: columns and rows are switched.

```
(mydata = Transpose@lists3) // TableForm
```

[image: mydata]

This is where the problem actually begins.  How can we add two additional columns (that is, the lists for countries and sports)?  So let's work with the remaining two lists.

```
(lists2 = {countries, sports}) // TableForm
```

[image: lists2]

So we can Join `Transpose[mydata]` and `lists2`....

```
(lists5 = Join[Transpose[mydata], lists2]) // TableForm
```

[image: lists5]

[Alternatively, we might have `Join`ed `lists3` and `lists2` because the second transposition, the transposition of `mydata` undoes the earlier transposition.
`lists3` is just the transposition of `mydata`. (and vice-versa).]

```
In[]:= lists3 === Transpose[mydata]
Out[]:= True
```

Now we only need to `Transpose` the result to obtain the desired final table of five lists, each occupying its own column:

```
Transpose@lists5 // TableForm
```

[image: final table]

I hope that helps shed some light on how to add two columns to a table.  I find this way reasonably clear.  You may find some other way clearer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I decided to start anew. Not that I think my approach is novel. I'm just trying find a clear way of explaining what's going on when we add columns via the double transpose method.

Comment: @David +1 for the thorough example

Comment: @David +1 yep, Transpose is the way to go.

Comment: @belisarius it is not necessarily the fastest, however.

Comment: @Mr. may be, but for a beginner it is the conceptual way to do things. Optimizing is *always* tricky.

Answer (score 4):

There are several things to cover here.  First, the following code does not give me any errors, so there may be something else going on here.  Perhaps you should post a full code block that produces the error.

```
mydata = Array[Subscript[{##}] &, {5, 3}];
myfirstlist = Range[1, 5];
mysecondlist = Range[6, 10];

Table[AppendTo[mydata[[i]], myfirstlist[[i]]], {i, 4}];
mydata // TableForm

Table[AppendTo[mydata[[i]], mysecondlist[[i]]], {i, 5}];
mydata // TableForm
```

Second, there is no purpose in using `Table` here, as you are modifying `mydata` directly.  `Table` will use up memory pointlessly.

Third, there are better ways to accomplish this task.

See [How to prepend a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244782/how-to-prepend-a-column-to-a-matrix) and [Inserting into a 2d list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270802/inserting-into-a-2d-list)

*I must retract my definitive statement that there are better ways.  After changing `Table` to `Do` and running a few quick tests, this appears to be a competitive method for some data.*

I am using Mathematica 7, so that does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: Same comment as Gareth above: i should run to 5 in both cases

Comment: @TomD If I read that help page, I forgot about it.  I tried to find the first page you linked, but I couldn't.

Comment: OK, thanks to all who replied. I'm new to stack overflow too, so forgive me if this is not the way to reply. I copied the code directly from the Mathematica "Appendto" documentation.

Comment: OK, thanks to all who replied. I'm new to stack overflow too, so forgive me if this is not the way to reply. I copied the code directly from the Mathematica "Appendto" documentation. The "applications" tab says "Assign m to be a 2x2 matrix: M={{a,b},{e,f}}." Then "Append a column to m:" In =col={x,y,z}; Table[AppendTo[m[[i]],col[[i]]],{i,3}]" Out={{a,b,x},{c,d,y},{e,f,z}}."

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278963/mathematica-appendto-function-problem/5279145#5279145), there are [better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1244782/198315) to adding columns to a list, and like [Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278963/mathematica-appendto-function-problem/5279137#5279137) and [Mr.Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278963/mathematica-appendto-function-problem/5279145#5279145), I do not seem to be able to reproduce the problem on v. 7.  But, I want to focus on the error itself, and see if we can correct it that way.  When Mathematica produces the message `Part::partw` it spits out part of the offending list like

```
Range[1000][[1001]]
Part::partw: Part 1001 of  
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,<<950>>} 
    does not exist.
```

So, the question I ask is which list is giving me the problems?  My best guess is it is `mysecondlist`, and I'd check `Length @ mysecondlist` to see if it is actually 5 elements long.

Comment: I found many people tend confuse {{1,2,3,4,5}} or {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}} for a list with five Integer elements. Perhaps something like that is going on.

Comment: @belisarius, definitely and the messages are tough to read, especially when they're flying at you. Hopefully, he'll take my suggestion and look closer at his data, or even the messages themselves. Crashing, however, implies that something else is going on, also.

Comment: I'll check the length. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's my two cents with what I believe is a very fast and IMHO most easily understandable construction.

First, some test arrays:

```
m = RandomInteger[100, {2000, 10000}];
l1 = RandomInteger[100, 2000];
l2 = RandomInteger[100, 2000];
{r, c} = Dimensions[m];
```

I increased the test array sizes somewhat to improve accuracy of the following timing measurements.

The method involves the invoking of the powers of `Part` ([[...]]), `All` and `Span` (;;).

Basically, I set up a new working matrix with the future dimensions of the data array after addition of the two columns, then add the original matrix using `All` and `Span` and add the additional columns with `All` only. I then copy back the scrap matrix to our original matrix, as the other methods also return the modified data matrix.

```
n = ConstantArray[0, {r, c} + {0, 2}];
n[[All, 1 ;; c]] = m;
n[[All, c + 1]] = l1;
n[[All, c + 2]] = l2;
m = n;
```

As for timing:

```
Mean[
 Table[
  First[
   AbsoluteTiming[
    n2 = ConstantArray[0, {r, c} + {0, 2}];
    n2[[All, 1 ;; c]] = m;
    n2[[All, c + 1]] = l1;
    n2[[All, c + 2]] = l2;
    m2 = n2;
    ]
   ],
  {10}
  ]
 ]

0.1056061
```

(an average of 10 runs)

The other proposed method with Do ([Mr.Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278963/mathematica-appendto-function-problem/5279145#5279145) and the OP):

```
Mean[
 Table[
  n1 = m;
  First[
   AbsoluteTiming[
    Do[AppendTo[n1[[i]], l1[[i]]], {i, 2000}]; 
    Do[AppendTo[n1[[i]], l2[[i]]], {i, 2000}];
    ]
   ],
  {10}
  ]
 ]

0.4898280
```

The result is the same:

```
In[9]:= n2 == n1

Out[9]= True
```

So, a conceptually easy and quick (5 times faster!) method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this but failed. I'm running Mma 8 on Windows XP; it doesn't seem like the difference should matter, but who knows? I said, successively,

```
myData = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {8, 9, 10}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
myFirstList = {9, 9, 9, 9, 9}
mySecondList = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6}
Table[AppendTo[myData[[i]], myFirstList[[i]]], {i, 4}]
Table[AppendTo[myData[[i]], mySecondList[[i]]], {i, 5}]
myData // TableForm
```

and got (0) no crash, (1) no errors or warnings, and (2) the output I expected. (Note: I used 4 rather than 5 in the limit of the first set of appends, just like in your question, in case that was somehow provoking trouble.)

The Mma documentation claims that `AppendTo[a,b]` is always equivalent to `a=Append[a,b]`, which suggests that it isn't modifying the list in-place. But I wonder whether maybe AppendTo sometimes *does* modify the list when it thinks it's safe to do so; then if it thinks it's safe and it isn't, there could be nasty consequences. Do the weird error messages and crashes still happen if you replace `AppendTo` with `Append` + ordinary assignment?

Comment: Your code is exactly like mine except my data is real numbers like 30.45. I'll try Append like you suggest. Thanks for replying!